# How can I permanently remove the games from Windows Mobile 2003?

Tags: games

I have a PDA with Windows Mobile 2003 installed on it.
It comes with two games: Jawbreaker and Solitaire.

I'd like to permanently remove these games from my device.
Using ActiveSync, I found the following files in the Windows folder. (There are some for Solitaire too)

[image: Jawbreaker Files]

These are located in the IPSM (Persistent Storage Memory) so any problems caused by deleting them wouldn't be fixable by a cold boot.

Is it safe to delete these files and will this remove the games from the system?

Comment: This place is only for Windows Phone not Windows Mobile.

Comment: @VitorCanova My understanding from Area 51 was that this *would* cover Windows Mobile, and Windows Phone powered devices

Comment: @VitorCanova In fact, the FAQ does say Windows Mobile **is on topic**

Comment: @RowlandShaw Your are completely right. I made a mistake. Sorry. Undo DownVote.

Comment: @VitorCanova Windows Mobile seems to be offtopic here http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/13/is-windows-mobile-on-topic

Comment: @Joe Yes, I'm following that thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, just rename them first, adding `_` to there extension or something similar.

Of course, this would suppose you still can obtain access to the device in case of failure. But none of these are required for you to reboot the device and/or launch ActiveSync, so I don't really see a problem.